# use json and javascript to populate a table

Tags: javascript, php, json, mysqli

I'm using php to fetch a db query that I want to make a table from. I want to put the query results into a json object and then use javascript from there to output the results into a table. I used json_encode to create the json object in php.

I'm fairly new to javascript so I'm a little confused as to how I can send the json object I've created to javascript and then output the results using javascript? Should I include the javascript in the same file as the php page or a different one?

If you can explain what you're doing that would be awesome because I really want to know what's going on at each step.

Here's what I have so far:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";


 $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

 if (!$conn) {
   die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

 $sql = "SELECT Name,
          Location,
          ID,
          Price

         From ProdTable
         where ID>=2000";

 $encode=array();
 $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
     $encode[] = $row;
   }
 echo json_encode($encode);

?>
```

Update:
So I went ahead and made xyz.php my backend page and made a main.php for displaying the results. I started off with this sample function to make sure my jquery was fetching the results from the xyz.php page. Now, I don't know how to display the results in a table using jquery.

Here's what I did for my main.php page:

```
      <?php

         ?>

        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
         $("button").click(function(){
         $("#div1").load("xyz.php");
          });
          });
        </script>

       <div id="div1"></div>
       <button>Show JSON Results</button>
```

Comment: `$sql = ""SELECT Name,` you've 2 double opening quotes. If it's not a typo, remove one `$sql = "SELECT Name,` - Plus, the trailing comma in `Price,` remove it. Had you used error checking, it would have signaled the errors. By doing that, may very well fix your code.

Comment: oops, that was a mistake, thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is:

Make the PHP file as backend. So that,

```
xyz.php:

// PUT YOUR CODE HERE
$sql = "SELECT Name,
          Location,
          ID,
          Price    
         From ProdTable
         where ID>=2000";

 $encode=array();
 $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
     $encode[] = $row;
   }
echo json_encode($encode);
?>
```

AND it should be accessible from the URL.

For example: `xyz.php?id=2000`

Now, on the page from where you want to populate this data, use jQuery

[$.post](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

And manipulate this json.

This will ensure your page loads faster as dynamic data is getting populated after initial page load.

Hope it works for you.

Comment: YW. But you missed something. Read my comment again ;)

Comment: @Fred-ii-, I think everything fixed now. :)

Comment: There you go. Now, it's best to point those errors out to the OP in your answer, as my comment may not survive ;)

Comment: I wasn't really sure how to use $post to manipulate the JSON data, but I went ahead and used another function to make sure that I could at least display the results. Can I also manipulate the json data from the function I made?